# how to run sphinx indexer comment (i.e. indexer even_idx --rotate ) through a php file

Tags: sphinx

how to run sphinx indexer comment (i.e. indexer even_idx --rotate ) through a php file in a server. I can run this command through ssh connection but not through any php file. Please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like either

1) Permissions issue, what ever user is running PHP does not permission to write to the sphinx data folder and index files. (ie php isnt the same user as running via SSH)

2) Paths. While indexer is found in the default path via SSH, its not in the one of PHP. So try specifing the full path to indexer (use `whereis` via SSH to find out)